# Cannot create any VM. Vagrant VM 'poweroff' state.

Tags: vagrant, osx-elcapitan, power-off

I have Mac OS X Capitan and Virtualbox version 5.0.24. When trying to run vagrant up I receive the error

```
A VirtualBox machine with the name 'xxxx' already exists
```

So I check the global-status and I find it already exists but in 'poweroff' state. When I try to resume it I get the error.

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'restoring, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.
```

I have reinstalled virtualbox with different versions but it cannot solve the problem. I have tried to destroy the VM but when I run vagrant up, I get the same problem again. In addition, I go to the GUI of Virtualbox and there is none vm there ( like it does not exist ). Any idea why and how could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM should appear when you run `vboxmanage list vms`

As vagrant gives you the name anyway, you can do the following

```
vboxmanage showvminfo 'xxxx'
vboxmanage unregistervm 'xxxx'
```

The 1st command will let you know where are the files associated with the VM. After you have unregistered the VM, you can remove them from disk.

You should now be able to run `vagrant up` again